# XQuery - Filtering by Date Range

Tags: xquery

I am trying to convert the following SQL Statement to XQuery

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE (OrderDate BETWEEN #1997/1/1# and #1998/1/1#)
```

This statement will return all records with an order date between 1/1/1997 and 1/1/1998#

I simpy am unsure of how to write the where statement. As the order date is written like this in the xml file

```
<OrderDate>1996-07-04T00:00:00</OrderDate>
```

This is now what I have but still doesn't work

```
for $x in doc("Orders.xml")/dataroot/Customers
where //Customers[OrderDate>1997/1/1][OrderDate<1998/1/1]

return $x
```

Comment: Which XQuery implementation are you using?

Comment: I am using Altova XML Spy - Xquery 1.0

Comment: I notice that you haven't accepted any answers. Do you still not have a working query?

Comment: Unfortunately that is correct, as none of these seem to be working in XML Spy, I am attempting to split the date to day month year

Comment: I just acquired a trial copy of XML Spy, and the code I gave in my answer works correctly there.

Comment: ...by the way, I would strongly suggest trying BaseX -- it has the shiny GUI editor and such, but also a much more recent XQuery implementation.

Comment: I very much appreciate your suggestion but as this is for my third year programming, they require the use of either Saxon or XML Spy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following has been tested to operate as expected on a current release of BaseX, and also in XML Spy 2012 :

```
let $doc :=
    <dataroot>
        <Customers>
            <OrderDate>1996-07-04T00:00:00</OrderDate>
        </Customers>
    </dataroot>

return $doc/Customers
    [xs:dateTime(./OrderDate/text()) gt xs:dateTime("1996-01-01T00:00:00")]
    [xs:dateTime(./OrderDate/text()) lt xs:dateTime("1998-01-01T00:00:00")]
```

...where the return is:

```
<Customers><OrderDate>1996-07-04T00:00:00</OrderDate></Customers>
```

...but then, grtjn's example operates correctly on BaseX, too, and doesn't rely on the query optimizer noticing that `OrderDate/text()` doesn't need to be casted twice to be efficient. Unless your code will be run in production against Altova's engine, I would suggest using something with a more recent XQuery implementation.

Comment: Thank you after modifying it, it seems to have worked. You are a godsend I very much appretiate it

Answer (score 3):

In plain XQuery you would write something like:

```
for $x in doc("Orders.xml")/dataroot/Customers
let $date as xs:dateTime := $x/OrderDate
where $date gt xs:dateTime("1996-01-01T00:00:00")
  and $date lt xs:dateTime("1998-01-01T00:00:00")
return  
    $x
```

HTH!

Comment: I still seem to receive an error when executing the code, error as follows

XQuery Execution Error!
Expected atomic item - current item is 'OrderDate' of type Element at xs:dateTime

Comment: @PeterRoche try making it `$x/OrderDate/data()` then. The general approach @grtjn is taking here, casting values to xs:dateTime for comparison, is the correct one.

Comment: @PeterRoche To my knowledge the parser should apply automatic type casting here, but perhaps I'm leaning on parser specific behaviour. The suggestion by Charles might work. If not, wrap his expression in an xs:dateTime type cast: `xs:dateTime($x/OrderDate/data())`